# AS3 Object To JSON

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert an array of objects (nested) to JSON string.
Here is my JSON output:

```
[{
    "Width": 570,
    "SessionID": 2003404006158805,
    "Price": "69,90",
    "PageCount": 24,
    "Pages": [{
        "ID": 1,
        "TemplateID": 0,
        "PageType": "cover",
        "TextContainers": [],
        "ImageContainers": []
    }, {
        "ID": 2,
        "TemplateID": 1001,
        "PageType": "single",
        "TextContainers": [],
        "ImageContainers": []
    }, {
        "ID": 3,
        "TemplateID": 0,
        "PageType": "double",
        "TextContainers": [],
        "ImageContainers": [{
            "Width": 570,
            "IsBG": true,
            "Brightness": 0,
            "Contrast": 0,
            "PosX": null,
            "ScaleX": null,
            "Height": 284,
            "ID": -1,
            "BlackWhite": 0,
            "PosY": null,
            "HasPhoto": false,
            "ScaleY": null,
            "PhotoID": null
        }]
    }, {
        "ID": 4,
        "TemplateID": 0,
        "PageType": "double",
        "TextContainers": [],
        "ImageContainers": [{
            "Width": 570,
            "IsBG": true,
            "Brightness": 0,
            "Contrast": 0,
            "PosX": null,
            "ScaleX": null,
            "Height": 284,
            "ID": -1,
            "BlackWhite": 0,
            "PosY": null,
            "HasPhoto": false,
            "ScaleY": null,
            "PhotoID": null
        }]
    }],
    "ProductSubID": 0,
    "Height": 620,
    "ProductID": 0
}]
```

And when I'm trying to convert this string to XML (at server side) comes out like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <0>
        <Width>570</Width>
        <SessionID>2003404006158805</SessionID>
        <Price>69,90</Price>
        <PageCount>24</PageCount>
        <Pages>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <TemplateID>0</TemplateID>
            <PageType>cover</PageType>
        </Pages>
        <Pages>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <TemplateID>1001</TemplateID>
            <PageType>single</PageType>
        </Pages>
        <Pages>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <TemplateID>0</TemplateID>
            <PageType>double</PageType>
            <ImageContainers>
                <Width>570</Width>
                <IsBG>true</IsBG>
                <Brightness>0</Brightness>
                <Contrast>0</Contrast>
                <PosX />
                <ScaleX />
                <Height>284</Height>
                <ID>-1</ID>
                <BlackWhite>0</BlackWhite>
                <PosY />
                <HasPhoto>false</HasPhoto>
                <ScaleY />
                <PhotoID />
            </ImageContainers>
        </Pages>
        <Pages>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <TemplateID>0</TemplateID>
            <PageType>double</PageType>
            <ImageContainers>
                <Width>570</Width>
                <IsBG>true</IsBG>
                <Brightness>0</Brightness>
                <Contrast>0</Contrast>
                <PosX />
                <ScaleX />
                <Height>284</Height>
                <ID>-1</ID>
                <BlackWhite>0</BlackWhite>
                <PosY />
                <HasPhoto>false</HasPhoto>
                <ScaleY />
                <PhotoID />
            </ImageContainers>
        </Pages>
        <ProductSubID>0</ProductSubID>
        <Height>620</Height>
        <ProductID>0</ProductID>
    </0>
```

But I need it to be like:

```
<pages>
<page>
</page>
<page>
</page>
</pages>
```

This is my AS code to convert Object arrays into JSON

```
var Pages:Array = [];
            var Books:Array = [];
            var JBook:Object = new Object();

            JBook.Width = Global.BOOK_WIDTH;

            for(var i:Number = 0; i<Global.PAGES.length; i++)
            {
                var Page:PageVO = Global.PAGES[i] as PageVO;
                var JPage:Object = new Object();
                JPage.ID = Page.ID;

                var ImageContainers:Array = [];
                var TextContainers:Array = [];
                var Template:TemplateVO = Page.ACTIVE_TEMPLATE;

                for(var j:Number = 0; j<Template.IMAGE_CONTAINERS.length; j++)
                {
                    var ImageContainer:ImageContainerVO = Template.IMAGE_CONTAINERS[j] as ImageContainerVO;
                    var JImageContainer:Object = new Object();
                    JImageContainer.ID = ImageContainer.ID;
                    ImageContainers.push(JImageContainer);
                }

                for (var m:Number = 0; m<Template.TEXT_CONTAINERS.length; m++)
                {
                    var TextContainer:TextContainerVO = Template.TEXT_CONTAINERS[m] as TextContainerVO;
                    var JTextContainer:Object = new Object();
                    JTextContainer.ID = TextContainer.ID;
                }

                JPage.TextContainers = TextContainers;
                JPage.ImageContainers = ImageContainers;
                Pages.push(JPage);
            }

            var Photos:Array = [];
            for(var p:Number = 0; p<Global.PHOTOS.length; p++ )
            {
                var Photo:PhotoVO = Global.PHOTOS[p] as PhotoVO;
                var JPhoto:Object = new Object();
                JPhoto.BMP = ImageUtils.BitmapToBase64(Photo.BMP.bitmapData);
                JPhoto.UseCount = Photo.USE_COUNT;
                JPhoto.ID = Photo.ID;
                Photos.push(JPhoto);
            }


            //JBook.Photos = Photos;
            JBook.Pages = Pages;
        JSON   = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(Books);
```

Any idea why it's rendering JSON string like they are not in the same node (seperate node for every page item)?

Hope I've been clear. Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just make the xml you want? ActionScript 3 has a fairly robust [`XML` implementation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html). But aside from that having a JSON structure that looked like: `pages: { page: [] }` would probably work.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the easiest way to convert from an AS3 object to a JSON string is to use the [JSON class from as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json).

Example usage:

```
var jsonString:String = JSON.encode(myDataObject);
```

It is probably best not to write your own parser, as the as3corelib JSON parser has been worked on and used by many people, for quite some time.

**EDIT:** @dpcao mentioned that you don't even need an external library anymore, [Adobe introduced a new JSON class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) available in FlashPlayer 11.

Example usage:

```
var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify(myDataObject);
```

Comment: Agreed, no need to <insert annoying overused statement about wheels>.

Answer (score 0):

Are you iterating through a native object?  Or through an XML Object?  Because if you're iterating an [XMLList][1] you should use length(), not length (they named it as a function to avoid name collections)

But honestly, use JSONLib, or [natively][2], with Flash Player 10.3 or above, use it natively.  It mimics the javascript api, with JSON.parse and JSON.stringify respectively.  This shouldn't be an issue with JSON serialization, you might have a bug either server side or client side with your serialization.  I would suggest adding a serialize() function to each of your objects -- this makes it easier in the long run to maintain anyways.  ie:

```
class PageVO {
  function serialize():Object {
    return {
       ID: some_id,
       Template_ID: some_template_id,
       // add image containers here
    }
  }
}
```

This will make it easier to debug individual objects to see where the problem is coming from.  As it looks, there's no reason why your code *shouldn't* work.  However, there might be issues with the actionscript serialization class and not adding a variable node: i.e. serializing [], rather than { "name": value }.  Try the native serializer and see what happens.  (don't forget -swf-version=16)