# convert class to object actionscript 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, class, sockets, actionscript

I`m tring to covert class to json.

The class is:

```
package com.globalData{

    public class userSite {
        private var uID:int,uName:String,uSocket:int,uZone:int,uRoom:int;
        public function user(ID:int,Name:String,ZoneID:int,RoomID:int,socketID:int){
            uID = ID;
            uName = Name;
            uSocket = socketID;
            uZone = ZoneID;
            uRoom = RoomID;
        }

        public function getName():String{
            return uName;
        }
        public function getID():int{
            return uID;
        }
        public function getZoneID():int{
            return uZone;
        }
        public function getRoomID():int{
            return uRoom;
        }
        public function getSocket():int{
            return uSocket;
        }
    }
}
```

Im tryed to do:

```
json(Object(roomVar));
```

But its not work (JSOn is function on the main class)

Im need to convert the class to json and send the json -> Socket
How can i do it?

Comment: you should post the code for your `json` function.

Comment: `public function json(obj){
return com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(obj);
}`

Comment: You say "convert class to JSON" but I suspect really you mean convert the content data **from** the class and send? Since you are already retrieving things like `Name` and `socketID` cant those be put into Strings or even Arrays/Objects and have that sent as JSON data? [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884492/as3-object-to-json) might help (see Adam Harte's answer)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code above:

1. It doesn't appear as though your `userSite` class has a constructor. Instead, you've opted to have a `user` function that takes in all of the initialization arguments
2. You're using functions where you should probably be using accessor methods, sometimes called a `getter`.

   - `public function getName():String { return uName;}` would become `public function get name():String { return uName;}`
   - Instead of calling `getName()`, you would access `name` as a property: `instance.name`
3. You're attempting to pass an `Object` to the `JSON.decode` method, this method expects a `String`. Something like `"{ 'a':1, 'b':[1,2,3] }"` would be an acceptable parameter. This would return an object with two properties `a` and `b`, `a` would contain the value `1`, and `b` would contain an array with the elements `1`, `2`, and `3`. What you are looking for is actually the `JSON.encode` method which accepts an `Object` and converts it to a `String` (which can be parsed as `JSON`).

I suggest you convert all of your `getXYZ()` functions to accessors, this will allow an instance of that class to be read as a collection of properties, which will in turn allow the `JSON.encode` function to create a `JSON` string object from it:

```
package com.globalData
{

        public class UserSite {
            private var uID:int,uName:String,uSocket:int,uZone:int,uRoom:int;
            public function UserSite(ID:int,Name:String,ZoneID:int,RoomID:int,socketID:int):void{
                uID = ID;
                uName = Name;
                uSocket = socketID;
                uZone = ZoneID;
                uRoom = RoomID;
            }

            public function get name():String{
                return uName;
            }
            public function get ID():int{
                return uID;
            }
            public function get zoneID():int{
                return uZone;
            }
            public function get roomID():int{
                return uRoom;
            }
            public function get socket():int{
                return uSocket;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
var roomVar:UserSite = new UserSite(1, 'Name', 2, 3, 4);
trace(JSON.encode(roomVar as Object));
```

**Output:**

`{"ID":1,"name":"Name","socket":4,"roomID":3,"zoneID":2}`